# Using structs, can't get it to print number of houses in code

Tags: c, struct

My printf's are all working except for 2. The question that I have is why won't my if statements print anything but 0? In the .txt file I'm using it is labeled as house as I have it labeled, I'm just curious if anyone can tell me why I'm only getting 0 as a value.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   struct properties
   {
   int properties;
   char type[20];
   float rcost;
   float mcost;
   int bedrooms;
   int bathrooms;
   };

typedef struct properties p;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *ifp;
  p A[50];
  p B[50];
  int n;
  int m;
  if (argc == 2)
  {
      if (ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r"))
      {
          fscanf(ifp, "%d", &n);
          int i;
          int house = 0;
          int house1 = 0;
          int house2 = 0;
          float totalrent = 0;
          float totalrentA = 0;
          float totalrentB = 0;
          float averagecostA = 0;
          float averagecostB = 0;
          float totalcost = 0;
          float averageprice = 0;
          for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
          {
              fscanf(ifp, "%s", &A[i].type);
              fscanf(ifp, "%f", &A[i].rcost);
              fscanf(ifp, "%f", &A[i].mcost);
              fscanf(ifp, "%d", &A[i].bedrooms);
              fscanf(ifp, "%d", &A[i].bathrooms);
              totalrentA += A[i].rcost;
              averagecostA = A[i].rcost / A[i].bedrooms;
              if ( A[i].type == "house" )
              {
                  house1 += 1;
              }
              //printf("%s\n", A[i].type);
              //printf("%.2f\n", A[i].rcost);
              //printf("%.2f\n", A[i].mcost);
              //printf("%d\n", A[i].bedrooms);
              //printf("%d\n", A[i].bathrooms);
          }
          printf("Total income Owner 1: $%.2f\n", totalrentA);
          fscanf(ifp, "%d", &m);
          for (i=1; i <= m; ++i)
          {
              fscanf(ifp, "%s", &B[i].type);
              fscanf(ifp, "%f", &B[i].rcost);
              fscanf(ifp, "%f", &B[i].mcost);
              fscanf(ifp, "%d", &B[i].bedrooms);
              fscanf(ifp, "%d", &B[i].bathrooms);
              totalrentB += B[i].rcost;
              totalcost += B[i].mcost;
              averagecostB = B[i].rcost / B[i].bedrooms;
              averageprice = (totalrentA + totalrentB) / (n + m);
              if ( B[i].type == "house*")
              {
                  house2 += 1;
              }

              //printf("%s\n", B[i].type);
              //printf("%.2f\n", B[i].rcost);
              //printf("%.2f\n", B[i].mcost);
              //printf("%d\n", B[i].bedrooms);
              //printf("%d\n", B[i].bathrooms);
              }
          printf("Total cost Owner 2: $%.2f\n", totalcost);
          printf("Average price per bedroom Owner1: $%.2f\n", averagecostA);
          printf("Average price per bedroom Owner2: $%.2f\n", averagecostB);
          printf("# of houses Owner1: %d\n", house1);
          printf("# of houses Owner2: %d\n", house2);
          printf("Average price of all properties: $%.2f\n", averageprice);
      }
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Correct Usage: ./<exec> <infile>\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: "why won't my if statements print " `if` statements are not for printing; use `printf` or a similar function.

Comment: I worded my question wrong, what I'm trying to figure out is my syntax incorrect to get the value I want from a .txt file, because my house1 and house2 values only come out as 0.

Comment: Why not fire up the debugger and see yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to understand whats passed in main (int argc, char *argv[]) if you're using it in your code.
"argc is the number of arguments being passed into your program from the command line and argv is the array of arguments." In other words, argc is number of argv so your first if condition if (argc == 2) is basically checking if the arguments from command line are 2 which I don't think is what you intended. Im most cases (or by default) the argument is 1 and its value is your directory.

In your second if condition you attempt to open a file with fopen passing argv[1] as the file name. This is valid but I suggest you first check that argv[1] is indeed your file name and not NULL.
And I'm not sure if you noticed but your for loop starts from 2 since ++i will increment it before hand unlike i++ which is post increment affecting the starting and ending points